# Unable to invoke `when` condition in strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

I can't make strategy.exit work properly when only `when` condition is set.
I have code written as follows:

```
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when=rsi(close, 14) < 30)
strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty_percent=100, when=rsi(close, 14) > 70)
```

if I add any other condition in `exit` the the selling is triggered. Can anybody please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the official documentation says

> If all the following parameters 'profit', 'limit', 'loss', 'stop',
>   'trail_points', 'trail_offset' are 'NaN', the command will fail. To
>   use market order to exit, the command strategy.close or
>   strategy.close_all should be used.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}exit

So it doesn't work with another params. `when` is only when to put order, but there must be at least some additional params, like 'profit'.

Use `strategy.close` if you want to exit by market.

There's actually a warning about that.

[image: warning]